# How to use a @Autowired bean inside a constructor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

Here is my class,

```
public class MyBusinessException extends RuntimeException {
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    private String errorCode;

    private String messageInEnglish;

    public MyBusinessException(String errorCode){
       this.errorCode=errorCode;
       this.messageInEnglish=messageSource.getMessage(this.code,null, Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
}
```

This is an exception class.When I pass the `errorCode` as a parameter to constructor it should populate the error message,That`s what I am looking for.Infact I want to instantiate the class like this

```
throw new MyBusinessException("MY-ERROR-CODE");//want to initiate like this(only one argument for constructor)
```

How to achieve something like this?

All these I have tried so far:

1. Constructor Autowiring.
2. Using `@PostConstruct`

Comment: what is happening when you do new MyBusinessException(...) now?

Comment: why would you do that? by just storing the errorcode you have all you need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> throw new MyBusinessException("MY-ERROR-CODE");//want to initiate like
>   this(only one argument for constructor)

You cannot use `@Autowired` with objects that are not created by Spring.
I think that you should refactor your code to provide to MyBusinessException constructor all information that needs.
You don't need to couple it with Spring.

The logic that is Spring dependent :

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource; 
...
messageSource.getMessage(this.code,null, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

could be moved to a Spring bean that will create a fully initialized `MyBusinessException` instance.
Besides, `messageSource.getMessage(this.code,null, Locale.ENGLISH)` may be required for other exceptions. Moving it this logic in a specific class makes sense.

```
@Bean
public class ExceptionFactory{
   @Autowired
   private MessageSource messageSource; 

   public MyBusinessException createMyBusinessException(String errorCode){        
      return new MyBusinessException(errorCode, messageSource.getMessage(this.code,null, Locale.ENGLISH));        
  } 
}
```

You can note that `createMyBusinessException()` provides a simple API for the clients : they need to pass only the error code `String` to create the exception.
The `MessageSource` dependency is a implementation detail that they don't need to bother with.

For example, this is enough :

```
throw exceptionFactory.createMyBusinessException("MY-ERROR-CODE");
```

Comment: Like your solution since you have to write the code to find the message only one time instead of n-times for every instantiation of `MyBusinessException`

Comment: Thank you. In your code, the statements to find the message are also performed a single time : in `MyBusinessException` constructor. The advantages of the current solution are rather : 1) separation of concerns : `messageSource.getMessage(this.code,null, Locale.ENGLISH)` may be required for other exceptions. Moving it this logic in a specific class makes sense. 2) Simplified API for the client : you don't need to pass at each time two parameters to create the exception. Just the error code string is enough.

Answer (score 3):

Dependency Injection does only work for instances that are created by Spring.

Since you manually initialize your exception you need to inject the `MessageSource` to the `@Component` throwing this exception.

Then you could either pass the `MessageSource` to the constructor of your `MyBusinessException` or get the message in the desired language and pass this message to the constructor.

```
@Component
public class MyComponentDoingBusinessLogic {

    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    public MyComponentDoingBusinessLogic(MessageSource messageSource) {
      this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    public void someBusinessLogic() {
      //Doing something
      if (errorState) {
        throw new MyBusinessException(yourErrorCode, messageSource);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you going to initialise anything if the exception isn't created by Spring?

Comment: added a small sample to make more clear what i described

Comment: @Yannic Klem Your solution is valid and not so bad at all :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `@Autowired` inside the ctor, as it was not yet initializaed by Spring.

The right way to do so, is to implement `InitializingBean`, which is basically Spring's ctor, and there (`afterPropertiesSet` method) you can use your injected fields.

Comment: This should probably be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way. An exception is constructed when it is thrown, which means that it won't get initialised by Spring. What you could do is to use a static method to get the current Spring application context, and get your bean from there.

Whether or not this is a clean solution is another issue, but you didn't ask about that.